# Spring Boot: Best way to translate error to error message detail?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, properties

I have a number of Spring Boot apps that all reference a common jar. In the common code, I have a list of exceptions that we encounter. I need to lookup these exceptions that are caught in the Boot apps and display a user-friendly error message. These exceptions and error messages need to be in a .properties file. What's the best way to do that? This is not I18N - just a lookup from a properties file.

These applications are structured like so:

```
 BootAppA
 |__src/main/java
 BootAppB
 |__src/main/java
 Common
 |__src/main/java
```

I'm not even sure if .properties file can be kept in the common jar? Again, the Spring Boot configuration doesn't live there - each application has its own configuration. They just share the common jar.

So for instance, if a HTTP 502 error occurs, I want to have a key-value in the properties file like this:

`502 Bad Gateway = AWS service is temporarily not available. ESS has been notified.`

I want to lookup the key `502 Bad Gateway` and get the value `AWS service is tempoarily not available. ESS has been notified.` I'm not sure how to go about it. All the messages I see on SO seem to concern I18N, and involve a configuration class, which my common jar doesn't have.

I've started with code that looks like this:

```
private static Map<String, String> errorsMap = new HashMap<>();
static {
    errorsMap.put("502 Bad Gateway", "AWS service is tempoarily not available. ESS has been notified.");
}
```

But I need to externalize this to a properties file. Does the key have to be single string, with no spaces? Maybe I need some sort of class to hold the exception and the user-friendly message? But then how would I look that up in a map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put a text file in whatever format you want in your resources folder and read from there.

```
   Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("classpath:data.txt");
   InputStream inputStream = resource.getInputStream();
   byte[] bdata = FileCopyUtils.copyToByteArray(inputStream);
   String data = new String(bdata, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Then just do whatever you want, i.e. split on commas or other character and populate your map. The key can be anything.